# Changing the address of a variable

Tags: c

Is there a way to set an integer variable at the absolute address `0x67a9` to the value
`0xaa55`? The compiler is a pure ANSI compiler.

How to accomplish this?

This is a program related to embedded systems. As in there we can access a specific memory location.

Comment: why would you want to do that ? what have you tried ? what doesn't work ? any error messages ?

Comment: I dont know how this can be done as we cant modify the address of the variable explicitly.

Comment: you can'T - you can only create a pointer pointing to that location and modify the value at that location through that pointer...

Comment: Thanks Yahia for making me to understand.. Pointer will hold the address.So we could able to change the address only with the pointer variable.

Comment: yes... see for example the answers of phoxis and Bill - they create a pointer to that location, then change the value at that address by assigning a value to the "dereferenced" pointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int *ptr = (int *) 0x67a9;
*ptr = 0xaa55;  // MBR signature ?
```

**EDIT**

You *cannot* change the address of a variable, you can only point to some address with a pointer, which is shown above.

Comment: Or better, `#define myvar (*(int *)0x67a9)` -- then it works just like an ordinary variable of type `int`.

Comment: *ptr=0xaa55 when i uesd this i got a run time error. I'm using visual studio2008.

Comment: naturally, because in an OS environment where the memory access is protected addressing some constant memory location like `0x67a9` is illegal, as you have not explicitly allocated it. You cannot just randomly use any address and access it in an OS with memory protection.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't change the memory address of a variable? A variable is just a name so you should be able to swap two names, right? Like in C# you can swap the names of two objects and they point to different memory locations.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

`*((int*)0x67a9) = 0xaa55;`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the compiler compiles I would think.

-If when compiling it decodes each instance of a variable to a final address you wouldn't be able to change the address of a regular variable.

-If when compiling it decodes each instance of a variable to reference a spot of a lookup table for its address this might be possible, though you best make sure the address you set it to is allocated.

For example say the 'lookup' address of variable A is 0x1000, and the value found at 0x1000 is 0x2000, so the contents of A is at 0x2000. To change the address of A you simply change the value at 0x1000. Set the value of 0x1000 to 0x3000 and then the contents of A is at 0x3000.

Ya this is how pointers work, but it might be possible that under the hood a compiler might treat them the same (regular variables simply being pointers that are automatically dereferenced.) Of course you could also just make all variables pointers and prepare yourself for a lot of de-referencing in your code.