# Does each variable in C/C++ point to a constant address in memory?

Tags: c++, c

I have 3 Questions:

In C/C++, variables basically hold an address that points to a memory location where the value is held.

For example:

```
int myVar = 5;
```

Here, *myVar* contains the address that points to a memory location that contains 5. If I change the variable value:

```
myVar = 10;
```

The memory address stays the same, but the value is overwritten.

1. **Is it possible to change what address *myVar* holds?** (I am not referring to pointers *, just normal variables)

How about for object variables:

```
class Box {. . .}
Box myBox;
```

In the above example, *myBox* variable basically holds the address to a location in memory that contains the object.

2. **Can someone change the address *myBox* references too?** (Again, I am not referring to pointers *, just normal variables).
3. **Does a normal variable hold a constant address in memory for the life of the program?**

Thank you guys for your time and understanding!

Comment: No, it's not possible. That's what pointers are made for. A variable allocates space *somewhere* (usually either automatic or static storage) and keeps track of that memory until its lifetime ends.

Comment: 1. No 2. No 3. For the lifetime of the variable, not the duration of the program. Memory locations can be reused after object occupying that memory is gone.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195088/changing-the-address-of-a-variable

Comment: "Does each variable in C/C++ point to a constant address in memory?" --> At least 2 exceptions: `myVar` is stored in a register, Code is optimized out..

Answer (score 5):

> In C/C++, variables basically hold an address that points to a memory location where the value is held.

That is not correct.  Variables are **objects** which *have* an address which does not change during the variable's lifetime and hold a value.

For C, this is described in section 6.2.4p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during
> which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
> has a constant address and retains its last-stored value
> throughout its lifetime.

So the address of a variable cannot be changed as it is constant throughout the lifetime of the variable.

It's also possible that a variable doesn't have an address at all.  If declared with the `register` keyword, it is not allowed to take the address of such a variable.  While the specifics are implementation defined, such a variable could reside entirely in a CPU register in which case it has no address.

If a particular variable never has its address taken, the compiler might also optimize away the variable's address and store it in a register.

Regarding your examples:

```
int myVar = 5;
```

Here, the variable `myVar` has some address, i.e. `&myVar`, and holds the value 5.

```
myVar = 10;
```

This changes the value of `myVar` to 10.

Comment: If it even has an address. Unless you take the address of a variable or pass it as reference and the call isn't inlined or otherwise optimized the compiler is free to not place objects in memory at all. It only has to behave *as-if* the object had a constant address. If the address isn't taken, directly or indirectly, a local variable might end up being stored at different places on the stack or in various registers during the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Good point.  Added details to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

The variable or object instance's name is its identifier, which provides an "abstract" way of accessing stored information within a program.

There is no way to control the memory address of a variable or object at runtime and the variable may not even be stored in memory.  For example, the compiler may choose to store local variables in a register rather than memory if they are only accessed briefly and it will optimize the program in some way.

For global or `static` variables, you may be able to use a linker script to fix its location for the duration of the program.  For local variables, they will either be placed into a register or be placed on the stack and assigned a location relative to the stack pointer.

Alternatively, you can declare a pointer, using `int * myVar;` or `Box myBox;` and assign it a specific memory location that will be used for storing information.  Although, in most cases a pointer assigned this way should be assigned to the address of another variable or object member by a reference `&` or dynamically using `new` or `malloc`.

In short:

1. At runtime, no.  At compile time, possibly, by using linker scripts and features.
2. No.  This would be treated the same as any other variable.
3. Static and global variables will hold the same address throughout the life of the program.  Local variables are placed on the stack and only "live" while the program is executing the block of code in which they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Memory address of a variable - if address exists - is always the same (and thus can't be changed), i.e., in your example, `&myVar` is the same *within scope*. That said, if the function reenters / recurses, then you might have *another* `myVar` that has a different address.

Also note, in practice you likely have some virtual memory management under the ABI that's managed by the OS. So, even if the logical address is the same, the physical address might be remapped. A practical use of this is seen in c++-based languages that do garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling & linking, named variables ARE addresses.
It is not that there is somewhere else something that "holds or contains" addresses.

Consider `int a = 5` declared within curly braces.
The compiler generates code that refers to bytes that are somewhere on the stack. With the function, references to 'a' are something like `SP+n`. That is, 5 is stored and accessed relative to the stack pointer at this point in the execution.

Answer (score 0):

> In C/C++, variables basically hold an address that points to a memory location where the value is held.

I would say that this is a significantly incorrect statement.

I would say that a variable basically *is* the address of a memory location where the value is held.

During compilation, the compiler typically constructs a *symbol table* which is a map of all the program's variables, and their corresponding addresses.

That map is typically modified by the *linker* which assigns final memory addresses to each variable and other object.

> Is it possible to change what address myVar holds?

No, it is not possible to do this.  It's not possible because it's not meaningful (or useful): since `myVar` *is* an address, there's nothing to change.

This analogy might be useful: Suppose you live at 123 Main Street.  You cannot simply call up the post office and say, you don't like this address, you want it to be 250 Main Street instead.  Once an address is assigned to a building, that address is generally fixed.  It's more or less the same with objects in a conventionally-compiled computer program.

(Why can't you change your address?  Because it would be too confusing.  Someone else might already have the address.  Even if not, people expect the house between 121 Main Street and 125 Main Street to be number 123, they would never expect to find number 250 there.)

Answer (score 0):

> *myVar* contains the address that points to a memory location that contains 5.

No. `myVar` doesn't store an address.  It's simply a name for an object that stores the value `5`.  That name is used by the compiler during translation to keep track of all the operations on that object, but it's not present in the resulting machine code.

> **Is it possible to change what address *myVar* holds?** (I am not referring to pointers *, just normal variables)

No, because `myVar` does not store an address; again, it's just a name for an object *in the abstract machine* that the compiler works against as it translates the code.

> **Can someone change the address *myBox* references too?** (Again, I am not referring to pointers *, just normal variables).

Same answer as above.

> **Does a normal variable hold a constant address in memory for the life of the program?**

For the lifetime of the variable:

> **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**
> ...
> 2 The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
> guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, **has a constant address**,<sup>33)</sup> and retains
> its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.<sup>34)</sup> If an object is referred to outside of its
> lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
> the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>33) The term ‘‘constant address’’ means that two pointers to the object constructed at possibly different
> times will compare equal. The address may be different during two different executions of the same
> program.
>
>
> 34) In the case of a volatile object, the last store need not be explicit in the program.</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>